# Multi Server Queue Simulation C++

Tags: c++

This assignment (I've linked the full description [here](https://web.stcloudstate.edu/bajulstrom/cs301/projects/p7f21.html)) asks us to create a multi server queue simulation (i.e. grocery store type scenario). My code seems to be working for the most part however I currently have 2 questions pertaining to my output that I am having a hard time answering.

1. Why does queue_total not match the actual number of elements displayed in each queue at the end of the program?
2. Why won't new items be enqueued to the shortest queue even though the shortest_queue function seems to be working?

The main code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "queue_2.h"
using namespace std;


// Utility function to return shortest queue.
int shortest_queue(Queue line[], int queuecount)
{
    int shortest = 0;

    // Condition 1: If a queue is empty 
    // with no active transactions, return it.
    for (int i = 0; i < queuecount; i++) {
        if (line[i].empty() && line[i].get_trans_time() == 0)
            return i;
    }

    // Condition 2: If a queue is simply empty, 
    // return it next.
    for (int i = 0; i < queuecount; i++) {
        if(line[i].empty()) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    // Condition 3: (otherwise) If all queues are
    // occupied check for shortest queue.
    for (int i = 1; i < queuecount; i++) {
        if(line[i].size() < line[shortest].size())
            shortest = i;
    }
    return shortest;
}

// Utility function to return total number 
// of customers waiting in queues.
int queue_total(Queue q[], int queuecount)
{
    int custcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < queuecount; ++i)
        custcount += q[i].size();
    return custcount;
}

int main()
{
    // Variable decelrations
    int trans_time = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int entry_time;
    int wait_sum = 0;
    int wait_time = 0;
    int seed = 3;
    int ariv_prob = 80;
    int MAX_TRANS_TIME = 12;
    int DURATION = 120;
    int queuecount = 4;
    int shortline;
    int temp;

    // Create a list of queues
    // and random number generator
    Queue line[queuecount];
    srand(seed);

    for (int time = 1; time < DURATION + 1; time++)
    {
        // Display the time
        cout << "Time: " << time << endl;

        // Check probablity only once per iteration
        if ( rand() % 100 < ariv_prob ) {
            shortline = shortest_queue(line, queuecount);
            line[shortline].enqueue(time);
        }

        // Update the transaction times for
        // the corresponding queues and compute 
        // summary statistics.
        for (int i = 0; i < queuecount; i++) {
            if ( line[i].get_trans_time() == 0 ) {
                if ( !line[i].empty() ) {
                    entry_time = line[i].print_front();
                    line[i].dequeue();
                    temp = (time - entry_time);

                    if(temp > wait_time)
                        wait_time = temp;

                    wait_sum += (time - entry_time);
                    ++count;
                    line[i].set_trans_time((rand() % MAX_TRANS_TIME) + 1);
                }
            }

            // Decrement and update transaction time.
            else {
                trans_time = line[i].get_trans_time() - 1;
                line[i].set_trans_time(trans_time);
            }
        }
        
        // Display status of the queues for the 
        // the given iteration.
        for (int i = 0; i < queuecount; i++) {
            cout << setw(4) << line[i].get_trans_time() << "  ";
            line[i].display();
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << count << " customers waited an average of ";
    cout << wait_sum / count << " ticks." << endl;
    cout << "The longest time a customer waited was " << wait_time << " ticks." << endl;
    cout << queue_total(line, queuecount) << " customers remain in the lines." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The queue implementation

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Queue {
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
    int count;
    int trans_time;

public:
    Queue() {
        front = rear = NULL;
        count = trans_time = 0;
    }

    void enqueue(int x) {
        // Create a new linked Node.
        Node* temp = new Node(x);

        // If the queue is already empty
        // then new node is front and rear
        if (empty()) {
            front = rear = temp;
            return;
        }

        // Add the new node at the end
        // of the queue and change the rear
        rear->next = temp;
        rear = temp;

        ++count;
    }

    void dequeue() {
        // If the queue is empty 
        // then we can return NULL
        if (empty())
            return;

        // Store the previous front and
        // move the front one node ahead
        Node* temp = front;
        front = front->next;

        // If front becomes NULL, then
        // Change the rear to be NULL as well
        if (front == NULL) 
            rear = NULL;

        delete(temp);

        --count;
    }

    // Utility function to check
    // if the queue is empty
    bool empty() {
        return (front == NULL && rear == NULL);
    }

    int size() {
        return count;
    }

    // Utility function to print front
    // element of the queue
    int print_front() {
        return front->data;
    }

    void display() {
        Node* temp = front;

        while (!(temp == NULL)) {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void set_trans_time(int i) {
        trans_time = i;
    }

    int get_trans_time() {
        return trans_time;
    }
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `enqueue` function doesn't increment (or set) the count when inserting into an empty queue. This causes the count to be 0 for a queue with 1 element.

The comparisons for `count > 0` or `count >= 0` before decrementing/incrementing it should be unnecessary. If those conditions are ever false then you have a problem elsewhere that caused the inconsistency.

Comment: I see what you mean. I added the constraints since I was getting negative values for the count for some reason, so I assumed that it was decrementing even when the list was empty. I'm pretty sure my empty function works, so the inconsistency isn't there. I've gone over main like 100 times, can't seem to find it lol. Also I updated the code and took out the if statements on the count

Comment: @FayZ In `enqueue`, the `if (empty()) { front = rear = temp; return; }` code will add a node to the queue but not change the count, so you have a queue with one node and a count of 0.

Comment: ahhh apologies for the confusion, yess. Thank you, the count is displaying the right values now.

Comment: To those who are curious, I got the project figured out now. The code has been updated to to the complete working version.